# Apple Mach-O Linker Error? Help please

Tags: c++

I get the following error when I try to compile my code:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"findCentralAtom(int, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm not sure what I have to do since I'm new to C++.

```
vector<int> findCentralAtom(int dist, const vector<string>& list) {
    int numAtoms = int(list.size());
    vector<int> centralAtom = {0,0};
    for(int i = 0; i < numAtoms; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < numAtoms; k++) {
            double temp = 0;
            temp = returnDistance(i, k, list);
            if(temp != 0 && temp < dist) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count > centralAtom[1]) {
            vector<string> tempVec = splitter(list[i]);
            centralAtom[0] = atoi(tempVec[4].c_str());
            centralAtom[1] = count;
        }
    }
    return centralAtom;
}

/*
int main() {
....
//caAtoms is a string vector
    vector<int> central = findCentralAtom(10, caAtoms);
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `central` as a `vector<int>` but the parameter to `findCentralAtom` is a `const vector<string>`  Those two type need to match.

EDIT: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but the comment in your code says: `//caAtoms is a string vector`  You call `findCentralAtom` with two parameters, an `int` 10 and `vector<string>` `caAtoms`.  `findCentralAtom` is declared `vector<int> findCentralAtom(int dist, const vector<string>& list)`  The first parameter `dist` is `int` which corresponds to your calling parameter `10` which is fine.  The second parameter is `list` and is declared `const vector<string>& list`.  The corresponding argument is `caAtoms`. You're passing a vector of strings to a function that expects a vector of int.  And that's why you're getting the linker error.

Comment: Is there a reason why they need to match? The vector central contains integers and is separate from the string vector parameter. Isn't it similar to returning an integer value from a string argument?